# c++ map/set iterator not dereferencable using .find

Tags: c++, dictionary, path-finding

I've relatively new to using maps, and I'm currently getting the `Debug Assertion Failed Expression: map/set iterator not dereferencable`

When I hit retry it brings me to this section of code:

`auto temp = mOpenMap.find(currentNode);
temp->second = false;`

I assume this has to do with the `.find(currentNode)` returning the end of the map, as it didn't find it, but the concerning part here is that doing my manual debugging I found that the only `Node` in the map indeed contained the exact parts of the `currentNode` I had it search for.

My map is this:

`std::map<PathNode*, bool> mOpenMap`

Optimistically what I would like it to do is search for the `row` and `column` to ascertain that it is looking at a node that has already been searched so that I can set the accompanying `boolean` to false.

What I'm wondering, is how do maps generally search for objects? Or better yet, how can I go about making the map search with a custom search?

Comment: Sometimes this can be an indication that you passed a map to a function by value instead of by reference, but that looks unlikely in this case.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should check `std::map::find` does find the element before dereference the iterator:

```
auto temp = mOpenMap.find(currentNode);
if (temp != mOpenMap.end())  // check temp is pointing to underneath element of a map
{
    temp->second = false;
}
```

Comment: This got rid of the error, but until I get rid of some more errors I won't know if it truly did the trick (make sure the paths are working correctly)

Comment: You need to make sure every iterator is valid when you try to find them STL container. btw, whats' the other errors?

Answer (score 1):

If all you're doing is tracking the presence of some `PathNode` or other, you'd be better off using a `std::set`.

As for a custom search, both `std::map` and `std::set` work with a collection of values, ordered by a comparator.  That comparator can be specified as the second template type when the map or set is defined.  If omitted, that comparator defaults to `std::less`, which simply compares the objects with the less than operator, `operator<`.  As written, your map `mOpenMap` is using the value of the pointer to perform this comparison, which is probably not what you want.

I suggest you declare and define `PathNode::operator<`, and replace `mOpenMap` with a member of type `std::set<PathNode>`.  This will key off of actual `PathNode` values, rather than pointers (which will probably never collide under normal circumstances).

Remember that your `PathNode::operator<` should generate a *strict ordering* of PathNode objects.  This is a requirement of the comparator for std::map and std::set. if you don't follow this rule, it will behave erratically, but it will compile and run, so make sure you pay attention to this detail.

- [Documentation for `std::set`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/set)

Comment: This isn't really an answer to the question, it should have been a comment.

Comment: It's a very good thing to have in the answers for others who may do the same thing I'm doing. A lot of people will just glance over the comments.

Comment: It's too long for a comment.  It's hard to really say if this is properly useful without seeing more code, but there's rarely ever a need for `std::map<anything, bool>` that a `std::set<anything>` doesn't handle more concisely.

Answer (score 1):

You should check the result as billz said. The most likely reason that the find failed is that your map is keyed on `PathNode *` meaning that it will only find nodes with an exact pointer match. Searching for a pathnode with the same member values as one in the map will not work.

If you need the map to be on `PathNode *`, then you will need to also supply a `predicate` as the third parameter of the map. The `predicate` will need to be written to compare two `PathNode *` parameters by their member values.